# Use someone else answer to make our own

Tags: discussion

I have something to ask about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649261/clicking-function-not-working-as-per-expected-in-ng-repeat). It was an easy answer, and someone give a good answer. After that, I add an answer too because for me, the code wasn't clean. There is 2 booleans (isShow, isHide) for the same thing. So I simplify this.

The fact is that in my code, there is a typo mistake. The 1st answerer edit his own answer to add the clean code and fixe my typo. I consider this as plagiarim, so I flag it (still in pending) and downvote his answer. He could just edit or leave a comment to fix my typo.

My question is, am I right ? Or I have a bad reaction ? Should I let a comment earlier ? Or maybe I'm completely wrong and his act was fine ?

Comment: Honest question: what makes you think the other answerer plagiarized and didn't just come to the same answer by him/herself?

Comment: Indpendent of whether the other poster actually took your code or not. Taking parts of other's answers, to create the "best possible answer" is OK, but of course, one should mention the source of the bits and pieces. However, I don't know what the recommended way to deal with plagiarim is. Downvoting a good answer seems wrong to me - the flag might be OK, but I don't know, what a moderator should do about it.

Comment: @MikeMB I think the downvote wasn't the best think to do too. It's mainly why I came ask here. Thanks for this informations.

Comment: @Jeroen He already has an answer and edit it just after I add mine to simplifies it just like me. Save the same var, ... the only one thing different is the name of a button.

Comment: Don't sweat it. This happens with easier questions: people will race eachother to an answer, often coming up with similar or even the exact same answer. If this puts you off, I'd recommend answering questions that are older than -say- 30 mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the other person plagiarized? Given the timestamps, it seems you're in "Fastest Gun in the West" territory, and it seems very likely that two people writing an answer would both come to *very* similar or even the exact same solutions.

So aye, I think you overreacted.

If you've written a truly unique answer that is highly distinctive, and if quite a while after that someone posts a very similar answer without attributing you, *then* you have good evidence of plagiarism. Even then, I'd recommend taking a friendlier or at least more neutral approach: post a neutral comment ("Hey, that's very similar to my answer? If you've used it in your answer, would you please add some form of attribution?"), and upon no/bad response flag for moderator help.

But in this case: don't sweat it. The main thing is helping askers, which happened, yeah?

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. Actually, it wasn't a "Fastest Gun in the West". He answers before me and give the right anwser. I just give an other answer to clean the code. He was accepted, it's logic, he corrected the problem 1st. So yeah it help the askers and it's good. It wasn't about this but more about the fact that he added the simplify code in his answer. But I've got it, my reaction was too much.